# Array asociativo multidimensional

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$lugares=array("lug"=>array("colonia"=>"sanfernanado", "direccion"=>23));
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo ir accediendo a los resultados, por ejemplo tratar de acceder al indice `colonia` y que me muestre el resultado correspondiente. y también me gustaría como agregar un nuevo indice con su respectivo resultado en el segundo `array`

Answer (score 2):

Como se trata de un Array `2D` podría tener 2 `foreach`  para obtener los datos,

```
foreach ($lugares as $key => $value) { // $key tendrá el valor de "lug" y value el array
    foreach($value as $k=>$v){ // Con value hacemos referencia al array más interno
    // $k hace referencia a las claves colonia y dirección , y $v hace referencia a 
   // los valores sanfernando y 23
        echo $v. "<br>"; 
    }
}
```

Para agregar un nuevo elemento tendría la siguiente sintaxis, especificando el nombre del `array` y entre corchetes **`la nueva clave`** , que será igual al nuevo `Array`.

```
$lugares["sluggg"] = array("colonia"=>"SanFranciso", "direccion"=>554) ;
```

Comment: gracias por responder, ahora comprendo

Comment: @OliverPeres sí una respuesta soluciona su problema, puede marcarla como aceptada. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías acceder a los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

$lugares=array("lug"=>array("colonia"=>"sanfernanado", "direccion"=>23));

echo $lugares['lug']['colonia']; // Imprime: sanfernanado
echo $lugares['lug']['direccion']; // Imprime: 23
```